# what amount ASP.NET that i need to learn for wif

Tags: asp.net, wif, claims-based-identity

I'm planning to use claim based identity in my graduation project, ه as i know i need to learn some ASP.NET,since there's no time to study the whole of ASP.NET i would like to know what are the core concepts of ASP.NET to learn in order to start using WIF.

Comment: That all depends on what you're intending to do with ASP.net and WIF.  What's the purpose of your project?

Comment: Actually , i would like to do some small proof of concept , A client page which access to some information in a service , this client page will be a quite simple , also i may need another page to manage the identities as i think , of course , some WCF exists.
Can I understand that WIF as a core doesn't need ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of my team have recently been working on introducing WIF into our existing products. From what I understand of the issues they've been having, you'll have a much easier time trying to design WIF in rather than retro-fitting it as they have.

However, I think it would still be sensible for you to understand Forms Authentication, as well as the ASP.NET page lifecycle. You'll obviously want to know more in order to make your site do anything interesting/useful, but from a purely WIF standpoint I would think you can start getting into it from there.

The whole point about WIF and STS' is that they are logically separated from the rest of your application or site - therefore you shouldn't need that much knowledge about ASP.NET to use WIF - in some ways it should be just like plumbing in your washing machine, you don't need to understand how the water gets to your house, you don't need to know in-depth how the washer spin cycle is programmed, you just need to know how to connect them.